# How does adverb placement affect the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I want to correct the following sentence so that it is grammatically correct and still conveys the original meaning:

> Many alcoholics attempt to conceal their problem from their fellow workers, but **invariably failing to keep their secret.**

The bold-faced part of this sentence is where the error occurs.

It would be great if you guys could help me **decide between these two choices.**:

1. but they invariably fail to keep their secret.
2. but fail, invariably, to keep their secret.

1 is good but lacks parallelism and is not as succinct (short and clear) as 2.

But the problem with 2 is its awkward adverb placement that might affect the original meaning.

Comment: I would use (3), ...but **invariably fail** to keep their secret. Preserves the parallelism and omits the superfluous *they* which simply refers to "many alcoholics".

Comment: @AndrewLeach, what is the difference if the adverb is placed before and after "fail"?

Comment: As an opponent of split infinitives, I would parse *fail invariably to keep* as linking the adverb with *keep* rather than *fail* (that is, "but fail to invariably keep their secret" if the infinitive can be split), which is subtly different.

Comment: So any adverb that goes between two verbs are ambiguous?

Comment: The main problem with the sentence is not the placement of the adverb. It's the use of 'failing' instead of 'fail'

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I know but these are the only choices I have.

Comment: @Doeser - Okay, I'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. but they invariably fail to keep their secret.
> 2. but fail, invariably to keep their secret.

1. is correct but would be better without the repeated 'they'. Note that 'invariably' qualifies 'fail', i.e. 'they invariably fail'.
2. is slightly odd because the comma places 'invariably' with 'keep'. The sentence now means that they don't keep their secret in an invariable manner. That has no meaning that I can understand.

Therefore the answer must be 1.

Comment: In **fail to keep invariably the secret**, does invariably also modifies "keep"? Is it a rule that adverbs also modify verbs that are placed immediately after them?

Comment: I would say that, purely because of the comma, 'invariably' *only* modifies 'keep'.  That is why I say the sentence doesn't make sense that way. The presence of the comma separates the adverb from 'fail' and yet clearly 'fail' is the verb that makes sense.

Comment: sorry I forgot to place the other comma.

Comment: In that case I don't particularly like either option. However, at least they are both possible now.